# EntityType '' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

im trying to add a database using code first to my sql management studio but i get the error "EntityType 'Question' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType" so i added the [key] to the model but i still get the same error.

This is my model:

```
  public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public Theme theme { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    public IList<Alternatives> alternatives { get; set; }
}
```

What else can i do so that it know this is the key?

Comment: are you using migrations? did you run `update-database` after making this change to the model?

Comment: I hade the wrong name on my context and in the web.config file but now i get this error: Invalid object name 'dbo.Questions